# How do I get the SPA to load with highest value tab?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've got a React SPA with Typescript. I'm using Material UI. I've created a loop to make a tab menu with the current months and all the previous months. It works correctly, apart from that I want the page to load with the last month as active.

I've tried doing some Google searches, but there doesn't seem to be someone that has the same problem as I'm having with a high value tab.

This is the render part of my code, feel that the rest of the code is not necessary for the problem.

```
render() {
  const month = new Date().getMonth();

  for (var i = month; i >= 0; i--) {
   rows.push(i);
  }

  const months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

  return (
    <TabHeader>
      {rows.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Tab
            key={index}
            value={item}
            label={months[new Date(0, 0).getMonth()+item]}
            component={Link}
            to={`/month/${item+1}`}
          />
        )
      })}
    </TabHeader>
  )
}
```

I would like to have the active tab when you enter the page be the highest value tab, in this current case, then that would be the month September with the value 8.

Comment: what is `TabHeader`? I dont see it in material ui docs, either way you probably meant to use `Tabs` which has `value` prop which you want to set in order to render activated tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Rikin in the comments, then it was a matter of passing the value into TabHeader which is a common component I made containing Tabs.